# Counting where the string appears in row with caveat - [R]

Tags: r

I have a dataset where the first three columns (G1P1, G1P2, G1P3) indicate one grouping of three individuals (i.e. Sidney, Blake, Max on Row 1), the second three columns (G2P1, G2P2, G2P3) indicate another grouping of three individuals (i.e. David, Steve, Daniel on Row 2), etc.... There are a total of 12 individuals, and dataset is pretty much all the possible groupings of these 12 people (approximately 300,000 rows). Each group's cumulative test scores are represented on far right columns, (G1.Sum, G2.Sum, G3.Sum, G4.Sum
).

[image]

```
#### The dput(data) of the first five rows ####
data <- structure(list(X = 1:5, G1P1 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("CHRIS", "DAVID", "EVA", "SIDNEY"), class = "factor"), G1P2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BLAKE", "NICK", "PATRIC", "STEVE"), class = "factor"), G1P3 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("BEAU", "BRANDON", "DANIEL", "MAX"), class = "factor"), G2P1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("CHRIS", "DAVID", "EVA", "SIDNEY"), class = "factor"), G2P2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("BLAKE", "NICK", "PATRIC", "STEVE"), class = "factor"), G2P3 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("BEAU", "BRANDON", "DANIEL", "MAX"), class = "factor"), G3P1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CHRIS", "DAVID", "EVA", "SIDNEY"), class = "factor"), G3P2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("BLAKE", "NICK", "PATRIC", "STEVE"), class = "factor"), G3P3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("BEAU", "BRANDON", "DANIEL", "MAX"), class = "factor"), G4P1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CHRIS", "DAVID", "EVA", "SIDNEY"), class = "factor"), G4P2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("BLAKE", "NICK", "PATRIC", "STEVE"), class = "factor"), G4P3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("BEAU", "BRANDON", "DANIEL", "MAX"), class = "factor"), G1.Sum = c(63.33333333, 63.33333333, 63.33333333, 63.33333333, 63.33333333), G2.Sum = c(58.78333333, 58.78333333, 54.62333333, 54.62333333, 58.69), G3.Sum = c(54.62333333, 58.69, 58.78333333, 58.69, 58.78333333), G4.Sum = c(58.69, 54.62333333, 58.69, 58.78333333, 54.62333333)), .Names = c("X", "G1P1", "G1P2", "G1P3", "G2P1", "G2P2", "G2P3", "G3P1", "G3P2", "G3P3", "G4P1", "G4P2", "G4P3", "G1.Sum", "G2.Sum", "G3.Sum", "G4.Sum"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I was wondering how you would write an R function so for each row, you can record where the person's group score ranked. For example, on Row 1, SIDNEY was in a group with the highest score at 63.3333. So his rank would be a '1.' But for BRANDON, his group scored last (54.62333), so her rank would be 4. I would like my final data.frame output to be something like this:

[image]

Comment: @PierreLafortune Ooops. I apologize. It has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
ranks <- t(apply(data[grep("Sum", names(data))], 1, function(x) rep(match(x, sort(x, decreasing=T)),each=3)))
just.names <- data[grep("P", names(data))] #Subset without sums
names <- as.character(unlist(just.names[1,])) #create name vector
sapply(names, function(x) ranks[just.names == x])
#      SIDNEY BLAKE MAX DAVID STEVE DANIEL CHRIS PATRIC BRANDON EVA NICK BEAU
# [1,]      1     1   1     2     2      2     4      4       4   3    3    3
# [2,]      1     1   1     2     2      2     4      4       4   3    3    3
# [3,]      1     1   1     2     2      2     4      4       4   3    3    3
# [4,]      1     1   1     2     2      2     4      4       4   3    3    3
# [5,]      1     1   1     2     2      2     4      4       4   3    3    3
```

We first rank the sums and replicate them 3 times each. Next we subset the larger data frame with the names only (take out the sum columns). We make a vector with the individual names. And lastly, we subset the ranks matrix that we created first by seeing where in the data frame the name appears.

Comment: I don't think the final output is correct? For example, on row 3, DAVID was on the 2nd highest group, but i think your output shows rank 4? Thank you for helping out with this by the way.

Comment: I updated the answer. Instead of using `order`, I wrote a custom ranking function `match(x, sort(x, decreasing=T))`

Comment: Hi Pierre. For some reason, when I apply a large dataset, the final matrix seems to be off. Objects, "ranks," "just.names," "names" store data properly but for some reason, sapply doesn't seem to output when I apply my real data which has over 300K rows. Is there any way I can get you the proper data and show you my error?

Comment: Are there repeats in the names? column names mislabeled? Three persons in every group? I can't see the data so you'll have to check everything. Run the code on pieces of the data. Try rows 1:1000, then the next thousand. Be a detective, somewhere in there you'll find something.

Comment: Hi @PierreLafortune. None of the names, columns, are misnamed/mislabeled. I've run the code in pieces as recommended, but somehow, if you run this on larger dataset, even the very first row of output seems to be wrong. For example, in our above example the five 5 rows are exactly the same with proper ranks. But when you run the code on larger data, the first 5 rows have "Blake" as rank 3, "Steve" as rank 4, and "Nick" and "Beau" also have rank 4. The first 5 rows are identical with the wrong ranks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. First, ranking, then uniting all the rows with their rank, converting to long data, separating out the variables, then finally spreading.

It got really long, and can probably be simplified:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data[ ,14:17] <- t(apply(-data[ ,14:17], 1 , rank))
data %>% unite("g1", starts_with("G1")) %>%
         unite("g2", starts_with("G2")) %>%
         unite("g3", starts_with("G3")) %>%
         unite("g4", starts_with("G4")) %>%
         gather(Row, val, -X) %>%
         select(-Row) %>%
         separate(val, c("1", "2", "3", "rank")) %>%
         gather(zzz, name, -X, -rank) %>%
         select(-zzz) %>%
         spread(name, rank)

  X BEAU BLAKE BRANDON CHRIS DANIEL DAVID EVA MAX NICK PATRIC SIDNEY STEVE
1 1    3     1       4     4      2     2   3   1    3      4      1     2
2 2    3     1       4     4      2     2   3   1    3      4      1     2
3 3    3     1       4     4      2     2   3   1    3      4      1     2
4 4    3     1       4     4      2     2   3   1    3      4      1     2
5 5    3     1       4     4      2     2   3   1    3      4      1     2
```

Comment: Hi @jeremycg, Do you think you can help explain what each step in data %>% is doing? I tried the earlier method, and I'm still having trouble with it, so I was hoping to use your dplyr method (which I'm only vaguely familiar with).

Comment: Sure, does it work for your whole data? the dplyr `%>%` (taken from magrittr) just passes the output of the previous command as the first argument to the next one. So, `3 %>% sum(4)` is the same as sum(3,4). You can stop the chain at each `%>%` and see the output. Ie: `data %>% unite("g1", starts_with("G1"))`, `data %>% unite("g1", starts_with("G1")) %>%
         unite("g2", starts_with("G2"))` etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using previous answer's 'rank' matrix and `library(reshape2)` to convert wide data.frame to long data.frame,

```
ranks <- t(apply(test[grep("Sum",names(test))], 1, function (x) 
    rep(match(x, sort(x, decreasing=T)),each=3))) 
colnames(ranks) <- names(test)[grep("P", names(test))] 
# data subset 
test_L <- test[,-grep("Avg", names(test))] 
df_player <- data.frame(position= names(test)[grep("P", names(test))],
                        t(test_L[,-1]), row.names = NULL) 
df_ranks <- data.frame(position=names(test)[grep("P", names(test))], 
                        t(ranks), row.names=NULL) 
# Combine two temporary data.frames
df_player_melted <- melt(df_player, id=1, 
   variable.name = "rowNumber", value.name = "player") 
df_ranks_melted <- rank= melt(df_ranks, id=1, 
   variable.name = "rowNumber", value.name = "rank") 
df <- cbind(df_player_melted, rank= df_ranks_melted$rank)
# cast into the output format you want
df <- dcast(df, rowNumber ~ player + rank)[1,]
```